# capture input of element when toggled with radio button and display outside of parent with only html and css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Im not sure if im designing my solution correctly but essentially I have two radio inputs and when i select an option it displays the anchor tag `.tick` which is fine. now I have an achor tag called `.some` that where I need to put the value of the selected anchor tags href attribute in some. is this possible? p.s. needs to be html and css only. no javascript. do I need to re-design my solution?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.option .tick {
    display: none;
}

.option input:checked ~ .tick {
    display: inline;
}
#happy1:checked ~ .some:after {
  content: " (happy1)";
}

#happy2:checked ~ .some:after {
  content: " (happy2)";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="step1">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="option">
                Option 1
                <input type="radio" name="select" id="happy1">
                <a href="happy" class="tick">Happy 1</a>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="option">
                Option 2
                <input type="radio" name="select" id="happy2">
                <a href="happy" class="tick">Happy 2</a>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="linktosomething" class="some">Some</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Im not sure how to go about doing this

Comment: _"now I have an achor tag called .some that where I need to put the value of the selected anchor tags href attribute in some."_ - which "some"? There are three of them here, `<a href="some" class="some">Some</a>`

Comment: @CBroe sorry typo I got rid of the irrelevant classes. see update. its the anchor tag at the bottom.

Comment: _"its the anchor tag at the bottom."_ - yes, which still contains _three_ somes `<a href="some" class="some">Some</a>`, so - which one(s) are you talking about? CSS can not "set" the value for attributes like href or class, if that's what you are asking about. _At most_ you could hide the text content of the link somehow, and then "replace" it via a pseudo element.

Comment: `.#happy1` - what kind of selector is that supposed to be? The leading dot would be the class selector, and a leading # would be the ID selector. `.#` does not make any sense at all. And even if you meant either a class or an ID selector here - there is no element with a class _or_ ID `happy1` anywhere in your HTML.

Comment: What you could do, is have _both_ the links you need in the bottom section of your HTML there, and then hide one and show the other, based on the selection above. But that's still not going to work with the sibling combinator `~` here - because your radio buttons, and those `.some` element(s) further down, are of course anything but siblings ... You'd have to work with `:has()` on an ancestor element here.

Comment: sorry ive made edits the id of happy1 and happy2 should be on the input controls. I just want to display specific content to the `<a href="linktosomething" class="some">Some</a>`  dependant on the input selected

Comment: Why is there a link inside your label elements here? That should generally be avoided - the user's expectation is that clicking on anything within the label, will focus the associated input, resp. toggle its state for a checkbox or radio button. Clicking on the link text here would navigate to the relative URL `happy`.

Comment: @CBroe yes true. it doesnt have to be an anchor tag it could be an image or anything I just want to display the content in the `some` anhcor tag based on radio button selection. i understand the ancestor issue and this is my question. if you could provide an answer that would be great

Comment: You more or less want something like a tabbed interface using CSS and radio buttons, so have a look at some existing implementations, such as https://www.codeinwp.com/snippets/accessible-pure-css-tabs/ or https://www.cssscript.com/create-responsive-tabs-component-using-css-radio-input/

Comment: yeah tabing effect is not what im looking for. do you know if this will work  `body:has(#happy1:checked) ~ .some:after{
      content: "happy1";
     }
 body:has(#happy2:checked) ~ .some:after{
      content: "happy2";
     }`

Comment: Visually it might not be exactly what you are looking for, but _functionally_, it is. Again, you can not set the `href` of the link using CSS - so if you want that to "change" based on your selection, then you need to have _two_ links in your HTML down there already, each pointing to one of the relevant target URLs - and then hide one and make the other one visible, based on the selection. So that is very much the same _principle_ as with those tabbed interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after playing around abit. I used the :has() and :is() functions

```
<div class="step1">
      <div class="row">
        <label class="option">
          Option 1
          <input type="radio" name="select" id="happy1"  class="tick1"/>
          <a href="happy1" class="tick">Happy 1</a>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label class="option">
          Option 2
          <input type="radio" name="select"  class="tick2" id="happy2" />
          <a href="happy2" class="tick">Happy 2</a>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="some" class="some"></a>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.option .tick {
        display: none;
      }

      .option input:checked ~ .tick {
        display: inline;
      }

      .some::after {
        content: " (default)";
      }

 body:has(#happy1:checked) ~ .some::after{
      content: "happy1";
     }
 body:has(:is(.tick1:checked)) .some::after{
      content: "sfdsf";
     }
    body:has(:is(.tick2:checked)) .some::after{
      content:"dvdfd"
     }
```

https://codepen.io/riobyucr-the-styleful/pen/OJdENYd